# How to access headers in an include directory from headers in another include directory?

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to include multiple directories using target_include_directories in one target, but headers in one include directory cannot access headers in another include directory. How do I solve this problem?

I tried putting the header files into add_library, but it doesn't help.
I have also searched here for two hours just now, but I cannot seem to find anything about it.

I am using VC++ by the way.

*The following project is simplified, the real project is [here](https://github.com/etaoinshrdlcumwfgypbvkjxqzaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa/unnamed).*

Project structure:

```
project
|-- CMakeLists.txt
|-- include
|   |-- project_header.h
|-- subproject
|   |-- CMakeLists.txt
|   |-- include
|   |   |-- subproject_header.h
|   |-- ...
|-- ...
```

`project/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
project("example")
add_subdirectory("subproject")
```

`project/subproject/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_executable(example "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/subproject/source/main.hpp")
set_target_properties(example PUBLIC_HEADER "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/subproject/include/subproject_header.h" PRIVATE_HEADER "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/project_header.h"
target_include_directories(example PUBLIC "include" PRIVATE "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include")
```

The problem is when I type this into `project/subproject/include/subproject_header.h`:

```
...
#include "project_header.h"
...
```

This will produce an error: `fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'project_header.h': No such file or directory`

How do I solve this problem?

**Edit:**

The problem seems to have fixed itself after using `..` instead of `${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}`. Then I change it back to `${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}` and it still works. Is this related to caching?

Comment: @Evg I typed the code without testing it so I type the full path to not risk. Also, the project shown is simplified one that closely represents the real project, but I will not type the full path in my real project. And I did use `add_subdirectory`.

Comment: You can run `make VERBOSE=1` and see which directories go into `-I` option.

Comment: I only use `project` in `project/CMakeLists.txt`. I have edited the post to make this clear.

Comment: I've just replicated your example, and cannot reproduce the problem. `-I<prefix>/subproject/include -I<prefix>/include` options are passed to the compiler.

Comment: I would just go with `target_include_directories(example PRIVATE "${PROJECT_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/../include")`

Comment: I think I will need to update my examples with real ones then.

Comment: @Evg The command line args is like yours, but it gives an error. It might have to do with other things then.

Comment: @KamilCuk I agree. It looks like the OP is essentially adding the same directory twice in this command: `target_include_directories(example PUBLIC "include" PRIVATE "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include")`. You need `..` to grab the `include` folder from the parent directory...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say my project is like this:

```
project
|---include
|   |---common.h
|---library
|---executable
```

`project/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
project(example)
add_subdirectory(library)
add_subdirectory(executable)
```

`project/library/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_library(lib ...)
target_include_directories(lib PRIVATE "../include")
```

`project/executable/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_executable(exe ...)
target_link_libraries(exe lib)
```

If I try to access `common.h` from files in `executable`, then the compiler will complain about the error mentioned above. This is caused by that PRIVATE include headers will not be included in its dependants.

**The solution is to add this to `project/projectB/CMakeLists.txt`: `target_include_directories(exe PRIVATE "../include")`**